# Copying a database and its tables to a new database its new tables, PHP only, no PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I need to do this in PHP only, can't use PhpMyAdmin because the process needs to be automated.

I've been using the following code to copy the database and its tables in to a new database with its new tables, with no change to table names, just change to database name.

Seems to work when the tables have 10 or so fields in them but I just added a table with 30-40 fields in it and it seems to fall down -as in, it doesn't copy the database table and it's table rows into the new database. Is there some error checking or buffering problems that I might be running into, or is it some other problem? Doesn't output a PDO exception error either.

here's the code:

```
$GLOBALS['MySQL_Host'] = "127.0.0.1";
$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username'] = "username";
$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password'] = "password";

$ExistingDatabase = "database_1";
$NewDatabase      = "database_2";

    // connect server 1
    $dblink1 = mysqli_connect("{$GLOBALS['MySQL_Host']}", "{$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username']}", " 
   {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']}", "{$ExistingDatabase}"); 

    // select database_1
    mysqli_select_db($dblink1,"$ExistingDatabase"); 
                    
    // get tables from database_1
    $tables = mysqli_fetch_all(mysqli_query($dblink1, "SHOW TABLES FROM $ExistingDatabase"));    
        
    // connect server 2         
    $dblink2 = mysqli_connect("{$GLOBALS['MySQL_Host']}", "{$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username']}", 
    "{$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']}"); 

    // select database 2
    mysqli_select_db($dblink2, "{$NewDatabase}"); 
                    
    $n=0;
    foreach($tables as $table){

        // get structure from table on server 1
        $tableinfo = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($dblink1,"SHOW CREATE TABLE $table[0]")); 
    
        // use found structure to make table on server 2        
        mysqli_query($dblink2," $tableinfo[1] "); 
        
        // select all content               
        $result = mysqli_query($dblink1,"SELECT * FROM $table[0]  ");         
                        
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {     
            mysqli_query($dblink2,"INSERT INTO $table[0] (".implode(", ",array_keys($row)).") VALUES 
            ('".implode("', '",array_values($row))."')"); 
                            
        }
        $n++;
    
    }
    
    mysqli_close($dblink1); 
    mysqli_close($dblink2);
```

I tried many (like 10) code snippets from stackoverflow and this was the only one I could get working. Is this a good approach? If not, what is? If so, how can I fix it to make sure it's more robust and actually works?

Remember I can't use PhpMyAdmin. Please don't close this post and link a PhpMyAdmin solution. Thanks.

**Edit**

I've tried the following commands and executions without success. Here's the top of the file, and the 4 trials I've tried are below it:

```
$GLOBALS['Dir'] = "C:/wamp64/www/projectsite/";

$dumpDir           =    $GLOBALS['Dir'].'Databases/';
$exisitingDatabase =    "exisitingDatabaseName";
$newDatabase       =    "newDatabaseName";

if(!file_exists($dumpDir)){
    mkdir($dumpDir);
}
$Dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3307", $GLOBALS['MySQL_Username'], 
$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']);
```

**1.**

```
$Dbh->exec("mysqldump --tab={$Dumpdir} {$ExistingDatabase}");
```

**2**

```
$Dbh->exec("-h {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Host']} -u {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username']} --password={$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']} > {$Dir_and_Filename}.sql");
```

**3**

```
$cmd = "mysqldump -h {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Host']} -u {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username']} --password={$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']} {$existingDatabase} > {$newDatabase}.sql";
exec($cmd);
```

**4**

```
exec("mysqldump -u {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username']} -p {$ExistingDatabase} > {$NewDatabase}.sql");
```

**Edit**

Managed to get this dumping an sql file so far:

```
$return_var = NULL;
$output = NULL;
$command = "$Dumpdir/mysqldump -u {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username']} -h {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Host']} -p{$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']} {$ExistingDatabase} > $Dumpdir/{$NewDatabase}.sql";
if(exec($command, $output, $return_var)){
        echo "asd";
    }else{
        echo "qwe";
    }
```

Comment: take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/copying-databases.html

Comment: How do you do that in PHP?

Comment: use the exec command from php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: I've been trying but I'm obviously doing something incorrect. If somebody can please point where :)

Comment: exec is not derived from $dbh it is a command of it self, also you shoult test the shell commands that you try execute first

Comment: Duplicate [Copying a database and its tables to a new database its new tables, works for tables with 10 fields but not 30](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662818/copying-a-database-and-its-tables-to-a-new-database-its-new-tables-works-for-ta)

Comment: There's no input from users at all. This is an internal script, that's housed within a class. Would it still be insecure or?

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

Here's some code that works, and it's simple too..

```
$Dumpdir        =   $GLOBALS['SiteDir'].'SQL/Dbs/';
        
        
        if(!file_exists($Dumpdir)){mkdir($Dumpdir);}

        $return_var = NULL;
        $output = NULL;
        $command = "$Dumpdir/mysqldump -u {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Username']} -h {$GLOBALS['MySQL_Host']} -p{$GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']} {$ExistingDatabase} > $Dumpdir{$NewDatabase}.sql";
        if(exec($command, $output, $return_var)){
            echo "uio";
        }else{
            echo "bnm";
        }
        
        
        $Dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3307", $GLOBALS['MySQL_Username'], $GLOBALS['MySQL_Password']);
        $Dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE $NewDatabase"); 
        
        $sql = file_get_contents($Dumpdir.$ExistingDatabase.".sql");

        $mysqli = new mysqli($GLOBALS['MySQL_Host'], $GLOBALS['MySQL_Username'], $GLOBALS['MySQL_Password'], $NewDatabase);

        /* execute multi query */
        if($mysqli->multi_query($sql)){
            echo "cvb";
        }else{
            echo "zxc";
        }
```

Comment: **Warning**: Do not use `multi_query()`. Whatever problem you are trying to solve with this function, there are plenty of better options you could do it instead. This functions is unsafe and should be avoided at all cost!

Comment: You are mixing PDO and mysqli. You should pick one only.

Comment: Since you are exporting the data using CLI, then you should also import it via CLI.

Comment: @Dharman What would you suggest in place of mysqli_query? I'm only new to commands, please illustrate.

Comment: `mysqli_query` is ok, I was talking about `multi_query`. You can use the same approach as you did with `mysqldump`. The CLI client can be used to both extract data and import it again. You do not need PHP to do this.

Comment: Oh ok. I'm restricted to using php because it's part of a php webapp. And do you mean doing `exec($sql)`? instead of multi_query? That would make sense.

Comment: And Dharman, it's not a duplicate question because I tried to tell you guys on the other question that I couldn't use PhpMyAdmin, I had to use PHP, so the suggested answer ya'll provided, and then closed my question, wasn't a solution.

Comment: If it is not a duplicate then you should edit the old one to make get it reopened. Don't reask the same question. It is not allowed on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that and get it reopened. They should mention that somewhere, it could've saved this embarrassment lol. Also, you know I'm not looking for a PhpMyAdmin solution don't you, I needed a php solution, and still do (now that you've pointed out it's flaws). So the answer you provided isn't an answer to my question. Marking another duplicate of a question that was unfortunately wrongfully answered is a tad trifling. How can I clear up this code? Can you suggest anything so I don't have to ask it again lol?